# How can I transform presence or absence of an observation to a matrix with the count of binary events in this format?

Tags: r, matrix, binary

I am trying to transform the input of a genetic imputer program to a different format, so I can use it in downstream analyses.
A toy example of what the input looks like would be:

```
input <- data.frame(A1 = c("a", "a", "b"), A2 = c("b", "a", "b"),
row.names = c("ind1", "ind2", "ind3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

     A1 A2
ind1  a  b
ind2  a  a
ind3  b  b
```

I need a matrix (or data frame, I don't mind) with two columns per individual and one row per possible observation. Then, if the two observations per individual are the same, there will be a "1" in the second column and that observation row. If not, there will be a "1" in the first column for both observations rows. The desired output would look like this:

```
output <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 6,
dimnames = list(c("a", "b"),
c("ind1_1", "ind1_2", "ind2_1", "ind2_2", "ind3_1", "ind3_2")))

  ind1_1 ind1_2 ind2_1 ind2_2 ind3_1 ind3_2
a      1      0      0      1      0      0
b      1      0      0      0      0      1
```

I have tried to create a matrix with all zeros, but then I struggle to locate the positions where there should be a "1", more or less like this:

```
observations <- sort(unique(c(input$A1, input$A2)))
individuals <- row.names(input)

output2 <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = length(observations),
ncol = length(individuals) * 2), row.names = observations)
colnames(output2) <- rep(individuals, each = 2)
```

Then, I was thinking about using an apply statement with a conditional function with different outcomes if the observations in each individual are equal or different. But if you come up with a different idea, I am open to suggestions. I wouldn't mind a solution in other similar language (python, perl...).

Of course, the reality is more complicated than that, so I would really appreciate a scalable solution. This is a sample of the original input with five measurements:

```
            ID locus allele1 allele2      prob     matching
397    FAM_308  HLAA   26:01   29:02 0.9805655 0.0006153191
677   FAM_2235  HLAA   03:01   03:01 0.9917792 0.0043972647
274 882_cas326  HLAA   01:01   02:01 0.8891524 0.0001758429
246 851_cas295  HLAA   02:01   03:01 0.9468442 0.0002267387
95  678_cas122  HLAA   02:01   02:01 0.9643058 0.0004104801
```

In the toy example, the individual IDs (row names) are in the ID column, A1 is the allele1 column and A2 is the allele2 column. The expected output would be as follows:

```
      FAM_308 FAM_308 FAM_2235 FAM_2235 882_cas326 882_cas326 851_cas295 851_cas295
01:01       0       0        0        0          1          0          0          0
02:01       0       0        0        0          1          0          1          0
03:01       0       0        0        1          0          0          1          0
26:01       1       0        0        0          0          0          0          0
29:02       1       0        0        0          0          0          0          0
      678_cas122 678_cas122
01:01          0          0
02:01          0          1
03:01          0          0
26:01          0          0
29:02          0          0
```

Thank you very much for your contributions!

Comment: couldn't you just make a new dummy column, which checks if `input$A1==input$A2`?

Comment: Here you have two types of observation (A1, A2), in reality too?

Comment: I am not able to understand the relation between your toy example `input` and `original input` ? Which are your `A1` `A2` columns in actual data ? Also can you show your expected output for the data shared ?

Comment: @heck1 No. I need to create an output file for a different program that requires the specific format I have explained.

Comment: @tom A1 and A2 are just the names of the columns, they mean observation one and two. In the toy example, the two types of observations are "a" and "b".

Comment: @RonakShah I have updated the question with additional information, thanks!

Comment: @cladigar Did you look at the edit in my answer? I am wondering if that solution works.

Comment: @teofil Sorry, I needed some time to understand the code, as I am not very experienced in using dplyr. It is clear that I should take a look at it! Regarding your answer, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, we can get all the `unique` values of observation. For each observation in each row we return output based on conditions. Bind all the results together and assign column and row names. First doing it on `input` data shared

```
unique_vals <- unique(unlist(input))
cols <- c(t(outer(rownames(input), c("_1", "_2"), paste0)))
output <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(unique_vals, function(x) 
   c(apply(input, 1, function(y) 
      if (all(y == x)) c(0, 1) else if (any(y == x)) c(1, 0) else c(0, 0)))))
names(output) <- cols
rownames(output) <- unique_vals


output
#  ind1_1 ind1_2 ind2_1 ind2_2 ind3_1 ind3_2
#a      1      0      0      1      0      0
#b      1      0      0      0      0      1
```

Now applying this on original dataframe (`df`)

```
vals <- c("allele1", "allele2")
unique_vals <- sort(unique(unlist(df[vals])))
cols <- c(t(outer(df$ID, c("_1", "_2"), paste0)))

output <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(unique_vals, function(x) 
   c(apply(df[vals], 1, function(y) 
   if (all(y == x)) c(0, 1) else if (any(y == x)) c(1, 0) else c(0, 0)))))

names(output) <- cols

output
#      FAM_308_1 FAM_308_2 FAM_2235_1 FAM_2235_2 882_cas326_1 882_cas326_2
#01:01         0         0          0          0            1            0
#02:01         0         0          0          0            1            0
#03:01         0         0          0          1            0            0
#26:01         1         0          0          0            0            0
#29:02         1         0          0          0            0            0

#      851_cas295_1 851_cas295_2 678_cas122_1 678_cas122_2
#01:01            0            0            0            0
#02:01            1            0            0            1
#03:01            1            0            0            0
#26:01            0            0            0            0
#29:02            0            0            0            0
```

It is not a good practice to have columns with same name hence adding `"_1"` and `"_2"` in the column name.

where `df` is

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("FAM_308", "FAM_2235", "882_cas326", "851_cas295", 
"678_cas122"), locus = c("HLAA", "HLAA", "HLAA", "HLAA", "HLAA"
), allele1 = c("26:01", "03:01", "01:01", "02:01", "02:01"), 
allele2 = c("29:02", "03:01", "02:01", "03:01", "02:01"), 
prob = c(0.9805655, 0.9917792, 0.8891524, 0.9468442, 0.9643058
), matching = c(0.0006153191, 0.0043972647, 0.0001758429, 
0.0002267387, 0.0004104801)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("397", 
"677", "274", "246", "95"))
```

Comment: It worked like a charm and just using base R, so thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with your dummy data. Should be easy to adapt to the real stuff.

```
library(dplyr)

A1 <- c("a", "a", "b")
A2 <- c("b", "a", "b")
In <- c("ind1", "ind2", "ind3")

alleles <- data.frame(In, A1, A2)

result <- 
  bind_rows(alleles, alleles, .id="Index") %>% 
  arrange(In) %>% 
  mutate(a=case_when(
    Index == 1 & A1 == "a" & A2 == "b" ~ 1,
    Index == 2 & A1 == "a" & A2 == "a" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )) %>% 
  mutate(b=case_when(
    Index == 1 & A1 == "a" & A2 == "b" ~ 1,
    Index == 2 & A1 == "b" & A2 == "b" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ))

reshaped <- result %>% 
  mutate(new_name=paste(In, Index, sep="_")) %>% 
  select(new_name, a, b) %>% 
  t

final <- as.matrix(reshaped[2:3,])
colnames(final) <- reshaped[1,]
rownames(final) <- c("a", "b")

final

  ind1_1 ind1_2 ind2_1 ind2_2 ind3_1 ind3_2
a "1"    "0"    "0"    "1"    "0"    "0"   
b "1"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "1"
```

**EDIT: A more general solution which avoids `case_when` for each allele. Works with the sample of real data (I think):**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ID <- c("FAM_308", "FAM_2235", "882_cas326", "851_cas295", "678_cas122")
allele1 <- c("26:01", "03:01", "01:01", "02:01", "02:01")
allele2 <- c("29:02", "03:01", "02:01", "03:01", "02:01")

DD <- data.frame(ID, allele1, allele2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% arrange(ID, allele1, allele2)
DD_long <- gather(DD, Allele, Value, -ID)

all_rows <- unique(DD_long$Value)
all_cols <- unique(DD_long$ID)

mm <- matrix(
  0,
  nrow = length(all_rows),
  ncol = length(all_cols) * 2 ,
  dimnames = list(all_rows, c(
    paste(all_cols, 1, sep = "_"), paste(all_cols, 2, sep = "_")
  ))
)

# function to fill rows, 
# but don't keep track of whether alleles match
fill_row <- function(row, mat) {
  x <- filter(DD_long, Value == row) %>% 
    mutate(z=paste(ID, gsub("allele", "", Allele), sep="_")) %>% 
    select(z) %>% unlist %>% unname
  cat("found allele ", row, "in individual ", x, "\n\n")
  mat[row, x] <- 1
  mat
}

for (i in seq_along(all_rows)) {
  mm <- fill_row(all_rows[i], mm)
}

# reorganize the 1s and 0s dependent on whether alleles match
reorganize_row <- function(row, col, mat) {
  if (sum(mat[row,grep(col, colnames(mm))]) == 1) {
    mat[row, grep(col, x = colnames(mat))[1]] <- 1
    mat[row, grep(col, x = colnames(mat))[2]] <- 0
  }

  if (sum(mat[row,grep(col, colnames(mm))]) == 2) {
    mat[row, grep(col, x = colnames(mat))[1]] <- 0
    mat[row, grep(col, x = colnames(mat))[2]] <- 1
  }
 mat 
}

# nested loop, sorry
for (i in seq_along(all_rows)) {
  for (j in seq_along(all_cols)) {
  mm <- reorganize_row(all_rows[i], col = all_cols[j], mat = mm)
  }
}

# sort the matrix to be as in example
nn <- mm[c("01:01", "02:01", "03:01", "26:01", "29:02"),
         c(
           "FAM_308_1",
           "FAM_308_2",
           "FAM_2235_1",
           "FAM_2235_2",
           "882_cas326_1",
           "882_cas326_2",
           "851_cas295_1",
           "851_cas295_2",
           "678_cas122_1",
           "678_cas122_2"
         )]
colnames(nn) <- gsub("_1|_2", "", x = colnames(nn))
nn

      FAM_308 FAM_308 FAM235 FAM235 882_cas326 882_cas326 851_cas295 851_cas295 678_cas122 678_cas122
01:01       0       0      0      0          1          0          0          0          0          0
02:01       0       0      0      0          1          0          1          0          0          1
03:01       0       0      0      1          0          0          1          0          0          0
26:01       1       0      0      0          0          0          0          0          0          0
29:02       1       0      0      0          0          0          0          0          0          0
```